# how to pass variable from PowerShell to batch variable

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I call the powershell command in batch and want to save the $tmpVersion to batch variable "version".

```
set version = powershell.exe -Command "$tmpVersion = (Get-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\myapp').DisplayVersion;"
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Like, remove `$tmpVersion = `, or add `$tmpVersion` to the very end?

Comment: `for /F "delims=" %%a in ('powershell.exe etc...') do set "version=%%a"`, but you need to also remove the `$tmpVersion =` part...

Comment: Don't use a batch file in the first place. Write the script in PowerShell.

Comment: Why not just use Reg.exe for this instead of a hybrid batch/script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `For` loop to save the result of a command as a variable:

`powershell.exe` example:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "RegRoot=HKLM"
Set "RegKey=SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\myapp"
Set "RegVal=DisplayVersion"
Set "Version="
For /F %%A In (
    'PowerShell -NoP -NoL "(GP '%RegRoot%:%RegKey%').%RegVal%" 2^>Nul'
) Do Set "Version=%%A"
If Not Defined Version Exit /B
Echo %Version%
Pause
```

`reg.exe` example:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "RegRoot=HKLM"
Set "RegKey=SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\myapp"
Set "RegVal=DisplayVersion"
Set "Version="
For /F "Tokens=2*" %%A In ('Reg Query "%RegRoot%\%RegKey%" /V "%RegVal%" 2^>Nul'
) Do Set "Version=%%B"
If Not Defined Version Exit /B
Echo %Version%
Pause
```

`WMIC.exe` example:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "RegRoot=&H80000002"
Set "RegKey=SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\myapp"
Set "RegVal=DisplayVersion"
Set "Version="
For /F Tokens^=2Delims^=^" %%A In ('WMIC Class StdRegProv
     Call GetStringValue hDefKey^="%RegRoot%" sSubKeyName^="%RegKey%"
      sValueName^="%RegVal%" 2^>Nul') Do Set "Version=%%A"
If Not Defined Version Exit /B
Echo %Version%
Pause
```