# Extract File's "Product Version" field using cmd

Tags: cmd, version, exe, product, wmic

I am new at batch scripting and looking for a way to extract the "Product Version" field of an .exe file using a command on cmd.

I did managed to get the regular "Version" field of a file using this command:

```
wmic datafile where Name="C:\\Users\\MyProgram.exe" get Version
```

is there any way to modify this command line for extracting the "Product Version" field?

Any other solution without wmic at all will also be good :)
thanks.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean. The Version field should be the "Product Version." You can use `wmic datafile where Name="C:\\Users\\MyProgram.exe" get /value` to see all the fields available to WMIC and compare that to the properties of the .exe file.

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try with this batch file to get easily your Product Version; in this example i tried with ***Google chrome*** :

```dos
@echo off
Title Get Product Version Using WMIC and Batch
Set FullPath=C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
Call :Get_AppName "%FullPath%" AppName
Call :GetVersion "%FullPath%" Version
If defined Version (
    echo "%FullPath%" ==^> v%Version%
    echo "%AppName%" ==^> %Version%
)
Pause
EXIT /B
::----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:GetVersion <FullPathApp> <Version>
Rem The argument %~1 represent the full path of the application without the double quotes
Rem The argument %2 represent the variable to be set (in our case %2=Version)
Set "FullPathApp=%~1"
Set "FullPathApp=%FullPathApp:\=\\%"
FOR /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%I IN (
    'wmic datafile where "name='%FullPathApp%'" get version /Value 2^>^nul'
) DO FOR /F "delims=" %%A IN ("%%I") DO SET "%2=%%A"
Exit /b
::----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:Get_AppName <FullPath> <AppName>
Rem %1 = FullPath
Rem %2 = AppName
for %%i in (%1) do set "%2=%%~nxi"
exit /b
::---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Or You can try with Powershell and Batch inspired from [Get File Version in PowerShell](https://www.delftstack.com/howto/powershell/powershell-get-file-version/) :

```dos
@echo off
Title Get Product Version using Powershell and Batch
Set FullPath=C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
echo %FullPath%
Powershell -C "(Get-Item '%FullPath%').VersionInfo.FileVersion"
Pause
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that it is the 'Product version' field which is shown in the Details tab of the Properties dialog for the exe-file you are looking for.

This is what it looks like for `C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe`:

[image]

Building on Qwertys comment to the original question, you can't get 'Product version' , only 'File version' (i.e. 'Version') using `wmic`.

Using **notpad.exe** as an example

The example below shows how to list all values that can be queried for using `wmic`,

```
C:\>wmic datafile where name='c:\\windows\\system32\\notepad.exe' get /value


AccessMask=1179817
Archive=TRUE
Caption=c:\windows\system32\notepad.exe
Compressed=FALSE
CompressionMethod=
CreationClassName=CIM_LogicalFile
CreationDate=20221020203835.352020+000
CSCreationClassName=Win32_ComputerSystem
CSName=PCS-SES-A
Description=c:\windows\system32\notepad.exe
Drive=c:
EightDotThreeFileName=c:\windows\system32\notepad.exe
Encrypted=FALSE
EncryptionMethod=
Extension=exe
FileName=notepad
FileSize=201216
FileType=Application
FSCreationClassName=Win32_FileSystem
FSName=NTFS
Hidden=FALSE
InstallDate=20221020203835.352020+000
InUseCount=
LastAccessed=20231115103558.131866+000
LastModified=20221020203835.352020+000
Manufacturer=Microsoft Corporation
Name=c:\windows\system32\notepad.exe
Path=\windows\system32\
Readable=TRUE
Status=OK
System=FALSE
Version=10.0.19041.1865
Writeable=TRUE
```

The 'Product version' field can be retrieved with Powershell like this:

```
Powershell -C "(Get-Item 'c:\\windows\\system32\\notepad.exe').VersionInfo.ProductVersion"
```

If you want to use batch-script you will have the challenge of getting the value back as a variable in your batch script. Looks like this answer describes how to do that: [how to pass variable from PowerShell to batch variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50104636/1688642)